# Pandas assign with comprehension giving unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use assign in pandas passing a dictionary comprehension.

Reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6],
    "weight": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
})

metrics = ["a", "b"]

df = df.assign(
    **{
        f"weighted_{metric}": lambda df: df[metric] * df["weight"]
        for metric in metrics
    }
)
print(df)
```

Results:

```py
   a  b  weight  weighted_a  weighted_b
0  1  4     0.1         0.4         0.4
1  2  5     0.2         1.0         1.0
2  3  6     0.3         1.8         1.8
```

I don't get the expected results, for a, I should get 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.

Do you know how can I get weighted_a correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `lambda` here since you use a comprehension to create columns:

```
df = df.assign(
    **{
        f"weighted_{metric}": df[metric] * df["weight"] for metric in metrics
    }
)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  weight  weighted_a  weighted_b
0  1  4     0.1         0.1         0.4
1  2  5     0.2         0.4         1.0
2  3  6     0.3         0.9         1.8
```

All `lambda` share the same memory address:

```
>>> [id(lambda df: df[metric] * df["weight"]) for metric in metrics]
[139806878308240, 139806878308240]
```

So the result will be the same for all columns.

If you want to use a `lambda` function, you have to evaluate it immediately like a standard function (but it doesn't have sense here):

```
>>> [(lambda df: df[metric] * df["weight"])(df) for metric in metrics]

[0    0.1
 1    0.4
 2    0.9
 dtype: float64,
 0    0.4
 1    1.0
 2    1.8
 dtype: float64]
```

> How would you call the function inside the dictionary with the comprehension?

```
def compute(metric, df):
    return df[metric] * df['weight']

df = df.assign(
    **{
        f"weighted_{metric}": compute(metric, df) for metric in metrics
    }
)
```

Comment: how would you use the lambda inside the assign? I have another case where the lambda is needed

Comment: You have to call it immediately if you use a comprehension `(lambda x: ...)(df) for i in ...`

Comment: but in this case, use a standard function instead of a lambda function. IMHO

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking about more complicated cases, to me it's still not clear on how to use the lambda inside the dictionary in assign

Comment: If it's complicated don't use `lambda` because this is not the right solution. Move the content of lambda inside a standard function `def f(x): ... return x` and call it in a comprehension.

Comment: just curious, why is not the right solution?

Comment: and how would you call the function inside the dictionary with the comprehension?

Comment: I updated my answer and added an example. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorized solution for multiple all columns by `weight` column and append to existing `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.join(df[metrics].mul(df["weight"], axis=0).add_prefix('weighted_'))
print(df)
   a  b  weight  weighted_a  weighted_b
0  1  4     0.1         0.1         0.4
1  2  5     0.2         0.4         1.0
2  3  6     0.3         0.9         1.8
```

Your solution should be changed by remove lambda function:

```
df = df.assign(
    **{
        f"weighted_{metric}":  df[metric] * df["weight"]
        for metric in metrics
    }
)


print(df)
   a  b  weight  weighted_a  weighted_b
0  1  4     0.1         0.1         0.4
1  2  5     0.2         0.4         1.0
2  3  6     0.3         0.9         1.8
```

Comment: so the issue is the lambda? do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

When using the assignment operator in combination with list comprehension in pandas, it is important to understand how the assignment works in order to avoid unexpected results. In pandas, assignments using list comprehension operate differently than regular assignments.

When you use list comprehension with pandas to create a new column or modify existing columns, it's essential to use the .loc accessor to correctly assign the values. This is because pandas requires explicit indexing when modifying or assigning values to subsets of data.