# Pandas assign with comprehension after query

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use assign in pandas passing a dictionary comprehension after a pandas query.

Reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6],
    "weight": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
})

metrics = ["a", "b"]

df = df.query("b > 4").assign(
    **{
        f"weighted_{metric}": lambda df: df[metric] * df["weight"]
        for metric in metrics
    }
)
print(df)
```

Results:

```py
   a  b  weight  weighted_a  weighted_b
1  2  5     0.2         1.0         1.0
2  3  6     0.3         1.8         1.8
```

I don't get the expected results, for a, I should get 0.2, 0.3.

Do you know how can I get weighted_a correctly?

I asked a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362880/pandas-assign-with-comprehension-giving-unexpected-results), the solutions in there worked fine, but not with a query before. Any thoughts on how to adapt the answers in the other question in a pipeline-ish manner?

Keep in mind may use a more complex function than just a multiplication for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `metric` as parameter to the lambda, else it will take the value of the last occurrence:

```
df = df.query("b > 4").assign(
    **{
        f"weighted_{metric}": lambda x, metric=metric: x[metric] * x["weight"]
        for metric in metrics
    }
)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  weight  weighted_a  weighted_b
1  2  5     0.2         0.4         1.0
2  3  6     0.3         0.9         1.8
```